# Forcing input video codec in ffmpeg for raw MPEGTS dump

Tags: ffmpeg, file-formats

I am trying to use ffmpeg to extract thumbnails from a partial dump of a MPEGTS, coming off a multicast network. The dump contains the video PID only, in MPEGTS format, but I am unable to get ffmpeg to recognize the HEVC, and I am looking for a command-line parameter to force it to decode it as HEVC.

This is what I am trying to run, and which is not working. Using "-f mpegts" it tries to probe the codec and fails:

```
ffmpeg -f mpegts -c:v:0 hevc -i dump.ts -vframes1 dump.jpg
ffmpeg version N-52628-g79e3c4dd74-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 43.100 / 56. 43.100
  libavcodec     58. 82.100 / 58. 82.100
  libavformat    58. 42.102 / 58. 42.102
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 80.100 /  7. 80.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[mpegts @ 0x6282180] probed stream 0 failed
[mpegts @ 0x6282180] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Unknown: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'dump.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:02.37, start: 59946.297300, bitrate: 16213 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x65]: Unknown: none
Output #0, image2, to 'dump.jpg':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Using "-f mpegtsraw" it says codec unknown:

```
ffmpeg -f mpegtsraw -c:v:0 hevc -i dump.ts -vframes1 dump.jpg
ffmpeg version N-52628-g79e3c4dd74-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 43.100 / 56. 43.100
  libavcodec     58. 82.100 / 58. 82.100
  libavformat    58. 42.102 / 58. 42.102
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 80.100 /  7. 80.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[mpegtsraw @ 0x6715180] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mpegtsraw, from 'dump.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:02.38, start: 59946.153588, bitrate: 16146 kb/s
Codec 0x20000 is not in the full list.
    Stream #0:0[0x0]: Data: unknown_codec, 16146 kb/s
Output #0, image2, to 'dump.jpg':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Comment: Dump the stream and then try: `ffmpeg -f mpegtsraw -i dump.ts -c copy -map 0 -f data stream.bin` and then `ffmpeg -f hevc -i stream.bin -vframes 1 dump.jpg`

Comment: With that, I get a green 1920×540 JPEG (with a gray upper-left corner), so it doesn't like the stream (I was trying something similar by modifying the code that generates the file, getting the same result as doing it with ffmpeg).